# How to determine how much memory 1 million particles in WebGL is using

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, debug

I would like to know how much memory is being used by a system of 1 million particles in WebGL:

[image]

I am not really too sure on what to look for in the performance/memory panels in the Chrome devtools / debugger.

Basically I would like to learn how to:

1. Know how much total memory is being used *just by the WebGL million particle portion of the code*, not all the extraneous stuff if possible.
2. Know how much each particle is using in terms of memory (e.g. by dividing the total by 1 million).

Any tips on how to accomplish this would be helpful, thank you.